# How to block or disable button's postback on textchanged event?

Tags: c#

For my 'UserName' field i am checking the exist name, if exist then will throw an error in label.so how to disable button's click event or postback?

```
protected void txtUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        string userName = txtUserName.Text;  
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)  
            connection.Open();

        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Get_UserName";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
        command.Connection = connection;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            lblUserNameError.Text = "Alredy Exist";
            lblUserNameError.Visible = true;
            //btnSave.Enabled = false; 
             //btnSave.onClientClick="return false";
             someID.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
        }
        else
        {
            lblUserNameError.Visible = false;               
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }  
    finally //Close db Connection if it is open....  
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }
}
```

above by three ways I still getting postback to page on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My textbox is inside an UpdatePanel also the Button has to be inside an UpdatePanel or else it won't be refreshed.

```
<asp:updatepanel id="uptxtUserName" runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown"><contenttemplate>
                                <asp:textbox id="txtUserName" runat="server" tabindex="8" autopostback="true">
                                        ontextchanged="txtUserName_TextChanged"></asp:textbox>
                                        <asp:label id="lblUserNameError" runat="server" visible="false" forecolor="Red"></asp:label>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="reqUName" controltovalidate="txtUserName" errormessage="Required" class="error" runat="server" forecolor="Red">
            </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            </contenttemplate>
                <triggers>
                    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="txtUserName" eventname="TextChanged" />
                    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="btnSave" eventname="Click" />
                    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="btnCancel" eventname="Click" />
                </triggers>
            </asp:updatepanel>
<pre lang="xml"><asp:UpdatePanel ID="upbtnSave" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" TabIndex="31" class="btn btn-success" onclick="btnSave_Click"></asp:Button>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" TabIndex="32" class="btn" onclick="btnCancel_Click"></asp:Button>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCancel" EventName="Click" />
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtUserName" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then code behind side will work like below

```
protected void txtUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
        {     
            try   
            {    
                string userName = txtUserName.Text;
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();


            command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = &quot;Get_UserName&quot;;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(&quot;@userName&quot;, userName);
            command.Connection = connection;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                lblUserNameError.Text = &quot;Alredy Exist&quot;;
                lblUserNameError.Visible = true;
                btnSave.OnClientClick = &quot;return false;&quot;;
            }
            else
            {
                lblUserNameError.Visible = false;
                btnSave.OnClientClick = &quot;return true;&quot;;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally //Close db Connection if it is open....
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
            connection.Close();
            command.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `YourTargetButton.Enabled = false;`

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    lblUserNameError.Text = "Alredy Exist";
    lblUserNameError.Visible = true;
    YourTargetButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I alredy tried with it.but still its going to post back.

Comment: try this: YourTargetButtonId.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");

Comment: I tried alredy and then still its going to postback, edited my above code.

Answer (score 0):

Should the `btnSave.Enabled = false;` be inside the `if` statement and not the `else`?
Seems to me that now you're disabling the button if same usernames are not found.

Comment: Does your txtUserName_TextChanged fire a postback? The button's attributes will only be changed on postback.

Answer (score 0):

When using the function: `btnSave.Enabled = false;`, after text changed event fired, is the button disabled in HTML page?
However, you can use this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').is(":visible")) {
            $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The script should be added into page which contains your btnSave.

You should add `<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript">` in to head tag: 
`<head runat="server"> <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"> </head>`.

Comment: for this which jquery library files required?

Comment: Yes insert in <content> and it uses Jquery's functions.

Comment: you mean have to use this<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is ok.

Comment: I tried with this but still getting post back.    '<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
 <script type="text/javascript">
     debugger;
     $(document).ready(function () {
         if ($('#<%=lblUserNameError.ClientID%>').is(":visible")) {
             $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         }
         else {
             $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
     });
</script>
</asp:Content>'

Comment: Dont add <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"> into that place.Please, look again the answer. I have edited to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the case but if your textbox is inside an UpdatePanel also the Button has to be inside an UpdatePanel or else it won't be refreshed
Also could you post the controls declaration